# How to set multiple types for a JsonSchema field in Json.Net?

Tags: json, schema, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How can I set Multiple type in a JsonSchema. 
The description field in the below example I want it to be JsonSchemaType.String or JsonSchemaType.null.

```
 {PropertyNames.Id, new JsonSchema { Type = JsonSchemaType.Integer, Required = true }},
      {PropertyNames.Description, new JsonSchema { Type = JsonSchemaType.String, Required = true }}
```

Also, I have an array which consists of Integers and float.

```
 result[PropertyNames.Metrics] = new JsonSchema { Type = JsonSchemaType.Array, Required = true, Items = new List<JsonSchema> { new JsonSchema() { Type = JsonSchemaType.Integer } } };
```

The validation fails as it expects integer but receives float. Can I do something like Type = JsonSchemaType.Integer "or" JsonSchemaType.Float

Comment: Don't put your Google Search in the title of your question.  *Put the question you're asking in the title.*

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using a simple `|` operator

```
result[PropertyNames.Metrics] = new JsonSchema 
{ 
    Type = JsonSchemaType.Array, 
    Required = true, 
    Items = new List<JsonSchema> 
    { 
        new JsonSchema() 
        { 
            Type = JsonSchemaType.Integer | JsonSchemaType.Null
        } 
    }
};
```